# Filter sublist using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

Using the following objects :

```
Order {
 int orderId;
 List<Item> items; 
}

Item {
 int price;
 String description;
 boolean free; 
}
```

The goal is to keep non-free items starting from an Observable<0rder> and still return an Observable<0rder>.

I'm doing the following for now, but my items doesn't get filtered :

```
    getMyOrder() // returns Observable<Order> from the network
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .flatMap(
       order -> Observable.from(order.items)
                        .filter(item -> !item.isFree())
                        .map(items -> order)
       );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't feel like something that should be done using RxJava (especially if you want to emit `Order` after the filtering step), could be an instance method in `Order`, for example:

```java
getMyOrder().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map(Order::removeFreeItems)
        .subscribe();

class Order {
    int orderId;
    List<Item> items;

    public Order removeFreeItems() {
        for (Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            if (iterator.next().free) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```