# RxJava take next item after filtered

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

So I have an ordered list and I'm trying to get the next item based on a condition (i.e. go through the list till find item, then get only the next one).

```
List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5});
Observable.from(items).filter(i -> i == 3) //.something here to get 4 after we match 3
```

Whats the least painful way to do this without using state/external variable etc.

Comment: if you are getting next item (instead of current one), I can't think of how that can be managed without state. Your condition is based on state.

Comment: This is kind of similar problem, with a solution that is thinking the problem other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491155/filter-sublist-using-rxjava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be done with skipWhile and take

```
  @Test
  void name() throws Exception {
    List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    Flowable.fromIterable(items)
        .skipWhile(integer -> integer != 3)
        .take(2)
        .test()
        .assertValues(3, 4);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, used a variation of this with firstOrDefault.